# How to delete the permalink (landing pages) of image in the media library in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, image, indexing, permalinks

I notice every image uploaded on wordpress website will have a separate page(a permalink to the image)

like this : https://www.knexusgroup.com/linkedin_logo_v1/

This is not good, how do I remove these page for every image? 
Every image have already CDN link.

I have got hold on images uploaded for blog post using `Yost plugin` but these images are uploaded to pages & are not attached to the particular page. These images are not looking good on the search result.

Please help me how can I remove this from wordpress.

Comment: consider adding more information about your issue.

Comment: Every image I upload on wordpress is being allocated a permlink like https://www.knexusgroup.com/linkedin_logo_v1/ and search engines will count this as a page as it has URL & index on the web. Above mentioned URL, once apear on the search result wont looks good and I don't want to display to users. So I want any image uploaded to wordpress wont get any permalink. Images can be referanced from cloud URLs.

Comment: not my area of expertise, but upvoting your question for others to see, although I doubt if this can be fixed

Comment: Thanks Inder. But this was not happening earlier till June. But I don't know what have been changed on website & all images got permalink and all images indexed as page on google which really not lookig good. Someone wordpress expert can help here I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a new file called image.php in your theme.
Insert the code below in your image.php file,

```
<?php
global $post;
if ( $post && $post->post_parent ) {
wp_redirect( esc_url( get_permalink( $post->post_parent ) ), 301 );
exit;
} else {
wp_redirect( esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ), 301 );
exit;
}
```

Comment: Post images are all attached & are being redirected. Issue is with the other images & images used on pages. All images are not attached to a particular page. I have Yoast SEO plugin where I am getting this redirection automatically, but this is not happening for pages.