# How to resolve WordPress post permalink structure for blog post in version 4.8.2?

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

I have very unusual issue on my `WordPress` website. In most of the blog posts custom permalink is working but there are few posts which are not following permalink structure like following

> This is the correct link structure to open the blog post :
>   https://www.knexusgroup.com/show/blog/how-to-win-at-real-time-marketing/
>
> But you can access this blog post like following URL also :
>   https://www.knexusgroup.com/how-to-win-at-real-time-marketing/

Blog posts which are correct, when you remove `/show/blog/` from URL it will reflect 404 error, but in this blog post, it is opening the blog post.

Can anyone help me here to understand the issue & how to resolve this?

> **Edit 1**

I have found what is the problem, and is post attachment & post have same `post_name`. However this should be resolved by solution [How to delete the permalink (landing pages) of image in the media library in Wordpress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51511945/how-to-delete-the-permalink-landing-pages-of-image-in-the-media-library-in-wor)

But this is not working in this scenario. We are using permalink structure `/show/blog/%postname%/` and I've observed which posts have permalink structure, there is no edit option in media attachment.

Comment: Maybe WP has cached old URLs from when before you changed to this specific permalink format?

Comment: I cleared all cache. And this URL structure is running from a very long time. I identified this issue early last month but not able to resolve. Seems very unusual kind of issue.

Comment: Well since canonical still seems to be set correctly even if the page is requested via the “wrong” URL, there is not that much of an issue here to begin with. I’d check the .htaccess and search the database for the “wrong” URL (the path portion of it), to see if it shows up anywhere in there maybe.

Comment: @CBroe Can help me here with SQL query to search what? I am not sure how to get on here.

Comment: Not talking about writing any queries manually, but something like phpMyAdmin’s search functionality.

Comment: thanks, your suggestion help me to identify the issue. But still not able to resolve. I shared in my post as Edit 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With idea of [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51614095/post-permalink-structure-not-working-on-few-blog-post-in-wordpress-4-8-2#comment90221234_51614095), I and Jaswant came to know attachment have same `post-name` as `parent post`.

So we **`deleted attachment`** of that post by searching in media library, and re added attachment to post, it works, this also fixed permalink of attachment with custom permalink and parent post.

> I found all duplicate URL by running MySQL query.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the parent page for each of yours pages. if the parent page is "show" so the link will be show/yout-page.

I hope I've helped you

Comment: no, I have defined custom permalink like "/show/blog/%postname%/" and this is working for 90% blog posts. But near to 10% blog posts are getting open without this structure too. Have included one example in my description.

Comment: I did pair up with @jaswant-singh, I found the attachment have same `post-name` as parent post but parent id is `0`, and some how attachment URL is opening without custom permalink structure, I tried to update parent ID, it resulted in 404.